# ls command different output in shell script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I have a strange behavior on my linux box and i want your advice.
I want to capture the output of this command

```
ls -log /some/directory
```

Running command from command line the result is OK:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 22650880 2013-09-09 12:02 file1.txt
-rwxr--r--. 1 20733952 2012-07-09 17:42 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 31596544 2013-09-09 23:42 file3.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 15773696 2013-09-10 11:15 file4.txt
```

so my final result using `awk` ( `ls -log /some/directory| awk '{print $6","$4" "$5}' | tr "\n" ";"` ):

```
file1.txt,2013-09-09 12:02;file2.txt,2012-07-09 17:42;...
```

My problem appear when I put `ls` command in a Bash script, because the date is converted. Instead of **2013-09-10 11:15** the result is **Sep 09 12:02**

How can i get the date like in command line output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of `ls` depends on the `LANG` environment. From `info ls`:

> By default, file timestamps are listed in abbreviated form.  Most
>   locales use a timestamp like `2002-03-30 23:45'.  However, the default
>   POSIX locale uses a date like`Mar 30  2002' for non-recent
>   timestamps, and a date-without-year and time like `Mar 30 23:45' for
>   recent timestamps.

Compare these two variants:

```
$ LANG=C ls -log
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 0 Sep 10 10:34 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 0 Sep 10 10:34 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 0 Sep 10 10:34 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 0 Sep 10 10:34 file4

$ LANG=en_US.utf8 ls -log
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 0 2013-09-10 10:34 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 0 2013-09-10 10:34 file2
-rw-r--r--  1 0 2013-09-10 10:34 file3
-rw-r--r--  1 0 2013-09-10 10:34 file4
```

But, as always, it is a [bad idea to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), because -- as you have seen -- breaks easily. Consider to use `stat` instead

```
for file in *; do
    stat -c "%n,%z;" "$file"
done
```

where you can specify which timestamp you want more precisely:

```
%x     Time of last access
%y     Time of last modification
%z     Time of last change
```

And you don't need `awk` anymore, too.

Comment: Thank you! I never used stat command. It works for what i need.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a date-format with your ls command:

```
ls -log --time-style="long-iso" /some/directory
```

This always results in the same date format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is good and strict to my question, but @mpy answer was more elaborate and give me another aproach to my problem.